# Create a NSMutableArray in xcode?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I need to create a NSMutableArray with dictionaries like the one shown below..Donno how to do it ./

```
(
        {
        businessName = "IBM Business Continuity & Recovery Service";
        city = "Costa Mesa";
        phone = "(714) 668-6900";
        state = CA;
        street = "600 Anton Blvd";
        zip = 92626;
    },
        {
        businessName = "IBM Sanno";
        city = Lomita;
        phone = "(310) 626-0613";
        state = CA;
        street = "25835 Appian Way";
        zip = 90717;
    },
        {
        businessName = "Ewert's IBM Typewriter Service";
        city = "";
        phone = "(559) 732-3215";
        state = "";
        street = "";
        zip = "";
    },
)
```

Please guide me

Comment: There is a concept of NSDictionary which incorporates the various uses of an NSMutable array... Please google it for reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

If you were planning on adding these dictionaries dynamically (roughly speaking):

```
NSMutableArray *dictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary *exampleDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"IBM Business Continuity & Recovery Service", @"businessName", 
@"Costa Mesa", @"city", 
@"(714) 668-6900", @"phone", 
@"CA", @"state", 
@"600 Anton Blvd", @"street", 
@"92626", @"zip", nil];

[dictionaries addObject:exampleDict];
```

Answer (score 3):

NSMutableDictionary *list = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

```
[list setObject:businessName.text forKey:@"businessName"];
[list setObject:city.text forKey:@"city"];
[list setObject:phone.text forKey:@"phone"];
[list setObject:state.text forKey:@"state"];
[list setObject:street.text forKey:@"street"];
[list setObject:zip.text forKey:@"zip"];

NSMutableArray *listArraySignup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[listArraySignup addObject:list];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `NSMutableArray` with dictionaries, you can do something like this

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 10];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: 10];

[dict setObject: @"IBM Business Continuity & Recovery Service" forKey: @"businessName"];
```

set other objects like this

```
[array addObject: dict];

[dict release];
```

Add the other dictionaries like this in the array and you will be good to go :)

Comment: @Divya this is the second time i'm editing an answer posted by you!strange

Answer (score 1):

with new Objective-C Literals

```
NSArray *array = @[
    @{
        @"businessName" : @"IBM Business Continuity & Recovery Service",
        @"city" : @"Costa Mesa",
        @"phone" : @"(714) 668-6900",
        @"state" : @"CA",
        @"street" : @"600 Anton Blvd",
        @"zip" : @(92626)
    },
    @{
        @"businessName" : @"IBM Sanno",
        @"city" : @"Lomita",
        @"phone" : @"(310) 626-0613",
        @"state" : @"CA",
        @"street" : @"25835 Appian Way",
        @"zip" : @(90717)
    },
    @{
        @"businessName" : @"Ewert's IBM Typewriter Service",
        @"phone" : @"(559) 732-3215"
    }
];
```

Comment: I'd prefer this method above John's approach. Probably because it's more readable

Answer (score 0):

try this one, use [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)